# How can I call the opencame function when I press the button python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a dashboard.py file, when I run it will show a screen containing the button, how can I display the button on the screen and when clicking on it will open the file face_detect, thank you everyone

```
from tkinter import *
class DashboardWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        # reset the window and background color
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.win, width=600, height=500, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        # show window in center of the screen
        width = self.win.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = self.win.winfo_screenheight()
        x = int(width / 2 - 600 / 2)
        y = int(height / 2 - 500 / 2)
        str1 = "600x500+" + str(x) + "+" + str(y)
        self.win.geometry(str1)

        # disable resize of the window
        self.win.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        # change the title of the window
        self.win.title("WELCOME | Login Window | ADMINISTRATOR")
        self.win.mainloop()`enter code here`

def opencame(self):
    import  face_detect
button = Button(text="OpenCame", font='Courier 15 bold',command = opencame())
button.pack()
```

Comment: Did you mean: ‘command = opencame’ ?

Comment: I used import face_detect in def opencam(self) but it's not working

Comment: See you shouldnt be calling the function using `()` instead remove the `()` and its recommended to have `import` statements on the top of your code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from tkinter import *
def opencame():
    import  face_detect
button = Button(text="OpenCame", font='Courier 15 bold',command = opencame)
button.pack()
button.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should change `command=opencame()` to `command=opencame`.

Second it really depends on how `face_detect.py` is written. For example, if `face_detect.py` is like below:

```
# face_detect.py
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Toplevel()
win.transient(win.master)

tk.Label(win, text='welcome to face detection', font='Helvetica 16 bold').pack()
tk.Button(win, text='Quit', command=win.destroy).pack()

win.grab_set()
win.wait_window()
```

A window will be shown if `OpenCame` button is ***first*** clicked.  However no window will be shown when the button is clicked again because the module has already been loaded.

However, if you rewrite `face_detect.py` as below:

```
# face_detect.py
import tkinter as tk

def open_window():
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.transient(win.master)

    tk.Label(win, text='welcome to face detection', font='Helvetica 16 bold').pack()
    tk.Button(win, text='Quit', command=win.destroy).pack()

    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window()
```

and rewrite `opencame()` as below:

```
def opencame(self):
    import face_detect
    face_detect.open_window()
```

Then a window will be shown whenever the `OpenCame` button is clicked.